# Kafka is falling when consumer start

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, consumer

I use kafka on windows, run zookeeper first through the console, then kafka. Everything starts perfectly. The producer runs fine as well. But as soon as I start the consumer, logs start pouring into the console and I get the map failed error. I tried to change the allocated memory in the kafka server start file.

At the moment my file kafka-server-start.sh it looks like this:

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms512M"
```

And if i delete KafkaListener everything starts up perfectly as well, but the interaction between the topics is important to me.

Kafka version: 2.13-3.2.1
Consumer property:

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapService;

public Map<String, Object> getDefaultConsumerConfig() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapService);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
    return props;
}
```

Consumer config:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, ConfigurationEventDto> configurationEventDtoConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaService.getDefaultConsumerConfig(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(ConfigurationEventDto.class, false));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConfigurationEventDto> configurationEventDtoKafkaFactory(
        ConsumerFactory<String, ConfigurationEventDto> configurationEventDtoConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConfigurationEventDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(configurationEventDtoConsumerFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

Kafka listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "activity-record-configuration-event",
        groupId = "activity-record-configuration-event",
        containerFactory = "configurationEventDtoKafkaFactory")
void listen(ConfigurationEventDto configurationEventDto) {
    log.info("new configurationEventDto received");
    service.save(configurationEventDto);
}
```

And when i start my consumer microservice kafka logs are:

```
java.io.IOException: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:938)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:124)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:54)
    at kafka.log.LazyIndex$.$anonfun$forOffset$1(LazyIndex.scala:106)
    at kafka.log.LazyIndex.$anonfun$get$1(LazyIndex.scala:63)
    at kafka.log.LazyIndex.get(LazyIndex.scala:60)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.offsetIndex(LogSegment.scala:64)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.readNextOffset(LogSegment.scala:453)
    at kafka.log.LogLoader.$anonfun$recoverLog$6(LogLoader.scala:457)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.scala:17)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at kafka.log.LogLoader.recoverLog(LogLoader.scala:457)
    at kafka.log.LogLoader.load(LogLoader.scala:162)
    at kafka.log.UnifiedLog$.apply(UnifiedLog.scala:1810)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1(LogManager.scala:901)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.getOrCreateLog(LogManager.scala:852)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.createLog(Partition.scala:372)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.maybeCreate$1(Partition.scala:347)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.createLogIfNotExists(Partition.scala:354)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$makeLeader$1(Partition.scala:566)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:543)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$makeLeaders$5(ReplicaManager.scala:1592)
    at kafka.utils.Implicits$MapExtensionMethods$.$anonfun$forKeyValue$1(Implicits.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$Node.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:633)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:499)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:1590)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:269)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:176)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

And of course i cleaned the folders with logs!

Comment: I solved this problem on my own. It was about the bit depth of the JDK. A 32-bit JDK was installed. After reinstalling everything worked successfully!

Comment: You are probably running non-production cluster, but there is a general idea of using same heap sizes for workloads like Kafka: e.g. same `Xmx and Xms`
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/deployment.html#jvm